# Using first() operator on an observable to get the first element

Tags: angular, operators, rxjs, observable

I am kind of new to RxJS, In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8EidlVWEU3EegJDvwsvl?p=preview)
I am trying to return the first member in the array, I have tried the `first()` operator but it returns nothing:

```
var one = this.http.get(this.memberUrl)
  .map( this.extractData )
  .map(processArray => {
  return processArray.filter(x=> x.type === "member")
  //.first()
  })
```

Whats wrong with the commented line in `app/member.service.ts`?

Answer (score 10):

When you use `.map()`, its argument is the type of the `Observable`.

Since the one you have in your service is an `Observable<Member[]>`, then `processArray` in

```js
.map(processArray => {
   return processArray.filter(x=> x.type === "member")
   //.first()
})
```

is an array - a `Member[]`.

Thus that `.filter()` you are calling is `Array#filter()` not `Observable#filter()`.

The same way the `.first()` you would be calling would be `Array#first()` not `Observable#first()`.

Since `Array` does not have a `.first()` array, it yields a runtime error ([**see plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uvZLxRDySulPiohOavEY?p=preview)).

---

Going further, if you instead call `.first()` at the `Observable`, you wouldn't see much difference, since it is an `Observable<Member[]>`, it would get the first element of that `Observable` which is the whole array.

---

## Solutions:

If you really want it to keep being an `Observable<Member[]>` and retrieve just the first member, you could do ([**see plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yfQKyQgaUXMnrpsNQbg3?p=preview)):

```js
.map(processArray => {
  console.log('pa2', typeof processArray);
  return [ processArray.filter(x=> x.type === "member")[0] ] // <-- [0] to get first item
                                    // wrap the result in [ ]s, because it expects an array
})
```

Though what I **advise** you to do is to turn the observable into an `Observable<Member>` (instead of `Observable<Member[]>`). You can do that using `.mergeMap()/.flatMap()`.

#### app/member.service.ts

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'; // <------------------ add this import

getMembers (): Observable<Member> { // <----------- changed from Member[] to Member
  var one = this.http.get(this.memberUrl)
    .map( this.extractData )
    .mergeMap(processArray => {  // <----------------- map to mergeMap
      return processArray.filter(x=> x.type === "member")
    }).first()                   // <----------------------- now you can use .first()
```

#### app/member-list.component.ts

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray'; // <------------------ add this import
...
getMembers() {
  this.memberService.getMembers().toArray() // <-------------- add .toArray()
                 .subscribe(
```

See [**final demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/u6OIq2CnBedu0kU3WrjD?p=preview).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to access the Observable's first member by using angular's async pipe.

ypurComponent.html

```
(yourObservable | async | slice :0:1)
```